# jquery dataTables data escape

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I'm trying to fix the problem, when you get data from customer, if they send data like `<div style="aClass: abc">show style</div>`, jquery dataTable will failed, how to prevent this happen?

The error in console is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined.

Any idea to prevent that?
Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to fix the problem, when you get data from customer, if they send data like <div style="aClass: abc">show style</div>, jquery dataTable will failed, how to prevent this happen?